# how to build kotlin-stdlib/kotlin-reflect from sources

Tags: kotlin, build

I need to build kotlin-stdlib/kotlin-reflect from sources (version 1.9.22).
I've setup JAVA_HOME to Java 17 and used `./gradlew build`.
But getting error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':kotlin-stdlib:compileMainJdk7KotlinJvm'.
> Unable to download toolchain matching the requirements ({languageVersion=7, vendor=any, implementation=vendor-specific}) from 'https://api.foojay.io/disco/v3.0/ids/45dfb704e8dcceab434285501d74cd33/redirect'.
   > Provisioned toolchain '/home/xxx/.gradle/jdks/zing20/zing20.09.1.0-1-jdk7.0.272-linux_x64' could not be probed: Command returned unexpected result code: 6
     Error output:
     Error: dl failure on line 1093
     Error: failed /home/xxx/.gradle/jdks/zing20/zing20.09.1.0-1-jdk7.0.272-linux_x64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so, because /home/xxx/.gradle/jdks/zing20/zing20.09.1.0-1-jdk7.0.272-linux_x64/jre/lib/amd64/server/../../../../etc/orca/lib/liborca.so.0: file too short
```

The `/home/xxx/.gradle/jdks/zing20` doesn't exist.
I've download and extracted `zing20.09.1.0-1-jdk7.0.272-linux_x64.tar.gz` and run again. Got this error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':kotlin-stdlib:compileMainJdk7KotlinJvm'.
> Unable to download toolchain matching the requirements ({languageVersion=7, vendor=any, implementation=vendor-specific}) from 'https://api.foojay.io/disco/v3.0/ids/45dfb704e8dcceab434285501d74cd33/redirect'.
   > Provisioned toolchain '/home/xxx/.gradle/jdks/zing20/zing20.09.1.0-1-jdk7.0.272-linux_x64' could not be probed: Command returned unexpected result code: 1
     Error output:
     Zing VM Error: Zing License Verification failed - no valid license found.
```

Is there a way how to build kotlin-stdlib/kotlin-reflect without zing20?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is problem of missing Java 7. To fix this there are two possibilities:

1. add Java 7 to a `$HOME/.m2/toolchains.xml`
2. add to `local.properties` (in the root of `kotlin` project) property `kotlin.build.isObsoleteJdkOverrideEnabled=true` - the Java 8 will be used to compile Java 7 related classes